# Calling Kotlin suspend functions from Swift/Objective-C is currently supported only on main thread

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to delete the fcm token from a user, and then logout.

But I cant do that because I receive the error `'Calling Kotlin suspend functions from Swift/Objective-C is currently supported only on main thread'`.

It seems that somehow the suspend function will suspend the next block?

The repo.deleteToken method:

```
 suspend fun deleteToken(token: String) {
        val userId = appService.currentUser!!.id
            realm.write {
                var user = query<UserInfo>("_id = $0", userId).first().find()
                if (user != null) {
                    user = findLatest(user)!!.also {
                        it.FCMToken.remove(token)
                    }
                    copyToRealm(user)
                }
        }
    }
```

and the repo.logout:

```
suspend fun doLogout() {
        appService.currentUser?.logOut()
    }
```

My logout method that deletes the token and tries to logout:

```
func doLogout(){
        
        repo.deleteToken(token: myFCMToken){error in
            isLoginShown = true

            repo.doLogout(){error in
                
            }
        }
    }
```

When I do the logout: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Calling Kotlin suspend functions from Swift/Objective-C is currently supported only on main thread'`

I know that there is a flag that can avoid that but I do not want to use that, I do not want to risk changing this.

How can I change the logout flow to first delete and then logout?

Comment: Watch Meet async/await and create Swift functions with your Kotlin functions that are compatible, it should only be a few lines of code and a continuation

Answer (score 5):

This restriction was made for old memory-model. If you use new memory model, you can disable this check in `gradle.properties`

```
kotlin.native.binary.objcExportSuspendFunctionLaunchThreadRestriction=none
```

You use new memory if you have `kotlin` 1.7.0+ and `kotlinx-coroutine` 1.6.0+ and not `native-mt`-version.

More details here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-51297/Native-allow-calling-Kotlin-suspend-functions-on-non-main-thread-from-Swift

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use experimental `kotlin.native.binary.objcExportSuspendFunctionLaunchThreadRestriction=none` flag, then you have only one option: execute your code in main thread, you can do it by wrapping callback in `DispatchQueue.main.sync` / `DispatchQueue.main.async`:

```swift
func doLogout() {    
    repo.deleteToken(token: myFCMToken) { error in
        isLoginShown = true
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.repo.doLogout() { error in 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Learn more [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/9/4/back-to-the-main-thread-dispatchqueuemain).

Comment: Is it possible to call Kotlin suspend from C